# Position Buttons inside UIStackView

Tags: swift2, ios-autolayout, uistackview

This sounds like a really simple issue but somehow I do not know how to easily solve it. Inside one row (UIStackView horizontal), I am trying to place two buttons (Cancel and OK) so that Cancel button will be at 1/4 (of the whole length) from left and Ok will be at the 3/4 (of the whole length) from left. I would like the buttons to be fixed length and not stretching to occupy the whole row.

Is there a way to solve it with just one UIStackView with 2 buttons? I am sure there a lots of alternatives (programing a view / use 3 UIStackViews).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope you can find an easy way  using equalWidthconstraints instead for UIStackView.

ie.
 1. You should place both buttons in a sam line.and make sure both button's width are same .
 2.then you select both buttons and put EqualWidthConstraint. 
 3.After that pin the left button with top,left and right .
 4.pin the right button with right,top spaces,
 5.then you double click on the equalwidthconstraints and give Multiplier as you needed ; like 1:4,3:4 something like that. Thank you

Comment: Thanveer, thanks for the answer. So it appears that you are proposing a containing UIView and do the setup as you mentioned (instead of using UIStackView). Is that right?

Comment: Yes,that is the best way for your current requirement..i hope so.